# children of tree now shown in extjs

Tags: tree, extjs5

Only the root element of my extjs tree (here Car) is shown but i cant figure out why. I use a tree store to represent the data and a TreePanel to display it.  My Ext-js version is 5.1. I tried out Firefox and Internet-Explorer with identical results. Any help would be welcome.

Here my store:

```
Ext.define('Example.store.DynamicCarStore', {
    extend: "Ext.data.TreeStore",
    model: 'Example.model.DynamicCarModel',
    root: {
        text: 'Root',
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

My model:

```
Ext.define("Example.model.DynamicCarModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
     fields: [{
        name: 'CarModel',
        type: 'string'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/WebTestExtJs2/example/example/test/',
        actionMethods: {
            read: 'GET'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'children' 
        },
    },    
});
```

the panel:

```
Ext.define('Example.view.DynamicTreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Dynamic Car Simple Tree ',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: null,
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        this.store=Ext.create("Example.store.DynamicCarStore");
        this.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
    },
    rootVisible: true,
    lines: true, // will show lines to display hierarchy.    
    useArrows: true, //this is a cool feature - converts the + signs     into Windows-7 like arrows. "lines" will not be displayed
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'name' // value field which will be displayed on    screen   
}]
});
```

and my json data that I read from the server:

```
[{
"success": true,
"children": [{
"id" : 1,
"name": "Cars",
"leaf": false, 
"expanded": true,  
"isvisible": true, 
"children": [{
    "id" : 2,
    "name": "Mercedes-Benz",
    "leaf": true, 
    "isvisible": true 
}, {
    "id" : 3,
    "name": "Audi",
    "leaf": true,
    "isvisible": true 
}, {
    "id" : 4,
    "name": "Ferrari",
    "leaf": true,
    "isvisible": true 
}]
}]
}]
```

Comment: The model and the JSON data don't match... The model describes "CarModel" as a string but the JSON just has a field "name"... The store describes the root element as a "Root" field which is also missing. And what do the lines `"invisible": true` in the JSON?

Comment: thanks a lot for the remarks, i changed "CarModel" to "name", commented out the root property of the store and removed the isvisiblue fields. Unfortunately no change at all in the output.

Comment: ah, i made an error while instantiating the panel. Now it works actually.